# What is the best way to search for an exact match using Postgres full-text search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, full-text-search, text-normalization

I have a Postgres database with around 1.5 million records. In my Ruby on Rails app, I need to search the `statement_text` field (which can contain anywhere from 1 to hundreds of words).

My problem: I know I can use the `pgSearch` gem to create scopes like `search_all_words` or `search_any_words`, but I'm uncertain what is the most efficient way to ensure only records with the **exact match** are returned in the result set.

That is, if I search "Pope Francis", I want it to find only those two words when they're consecutive and in the same order (as opposed to, say, "The pope is named Francis").

So far, I've just combined a GIN index with `ILIKE` for exact match searches. But given that a GIN index essentially works by [storing the exact position of a word](http://rachbelaid.com/postgres-full-text-search-is-good-enough/) in every record, shouldn't there be a more efficient (non-`ILIKE`) way of ensuring that the search term is an exact match with the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, full-text requires word stemming based on language dictionary used, so with With Full-Text search you can use [`ts_rank()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html) function without *stemming* and with `'simple'` dictionary to determine the relevance of the phrase you are searching for.

```
WITH t(v) AS ( VALUES
  ('Test sentence with Pope Francis'),
  ('Test Francis sentence with Pope '),
  ('The pope is named Francis')
)
SELECT v,ts_rank(tsv,q) as rank
FROM t,
    to_tsvector('simple',v) as tsv,
    plainto_tsquery('simple','Pope Francis') AS q;
```

Result:

```
                v                 |   rank    
----------------------------------+-----------
 Test sentence with Pope Francis  | 0.0991032
 Test Francis sentence with Pope  | 0.0973585
 The pope is named Francis        | 0.0973585
(3 rows)
```

Without full-text search, you can implement just faster `ILIKE` pattern matching with [**`pg_trgm`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) extension. Example is [**here**](http://www.depesz.com/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/).

Comment: Thanks, Dmitry! I am using full-text search so I can use ts_rank. The problem, though, is that -- depending on the field's word count -- there's no specific cutoff which will ensure that the words are adjacent and in the correct order, without using ILIKE. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: no, there is no cut off based on the length. If there is a match for phrase, it will still have higher rank. you may omit normalization factor for ts_rank - it should work fine.